# PHP echo JQuery Click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get some jquery to click on a div.
I've got the ID of the div that I need to be clicked and it's inside some php code:

```
if(isset($_GET['something'])) {

 echo "<script> $('#huge_it_dots_3_20').click(); </script>";

}
```

The div I'm targetting looks like this:

```
<div id="huge_it_dots_3_20" class="huge_it_slideshow_dots_20 huge_it_slideshow_dots_deactive_20" image_key="3" image_id="33" onclick="huge_it_change_image_20(parseInt(jQuery('#huge_it_current_image_key_20').val()), '3', data_20,false,true);return false;"></div>
```

My issue is that for some reason it's not clicking on the div.

And ideas why?

Comment: where did you put your php code? above?or below the div?

Comment: Try with this:   echo "<script> $('#huge_it_dots_3_20').trigger("click"); </script>";

Comment: declare the method in the domReady event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
echo "<script> $('#huge_it_dots_3_20').trigger('click'); </script>";
```

Comment: if you paste this code before the HTML element itself, it won't trigger anything. [proof here](http://jsfiddle.net/kod7z3hw/1/) , but, if you check up my answer with the `readyState` you'll see it works. [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pu0591L0/)

Answer (score 2):

warp the code with dom ready function.. then it should work

```
  if(isset($_GET['something'])) {

     echo "<script> $(document).ready(function(){$('#huge_it_dots_3_20').click();}) </script>";

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['something'])) { ?>

 <script> 
  $('#huge_it_dots_3_20').click();
 </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The JS code will run before your DOM will be ready so.. here's a readyState.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['something'])) { ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function(){ 
             $("#huge_it_dots_3_20").click()
         });
    </script>

<?php } ?>
```